# Zingcharts live feed not rendering chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, visualization, zingchart

So I have been trying out ZingCharts which in general I like a ton. But now I am trying to create a live feed and the [documentation](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/feeds/) isn't all that clear. I am trying to use HTTP to update a chart with new values. It seems that I need to have a page that is sending the chart data with updated values and that is what I am doing. This chart renders correctly when I past the JSON directly in the browser but not as a live feed, it now only *emphasized text*correctly pulls from the /metrics_feed and renders the outline of the chart but it is all grey. The JSON I am sending over HTTP is:

```
{
  "crosshair-x": {},
  "legend": {},
  "plot": {
    "valueBox": {
      "placement": "top",
      "type": "max, min",
      "visible": false
    }
  },
  "scaleX": {
    "label": {
      "text": "Metric count"
    }
  },
  "scaleY": {
    "label": {
      "text": "Metric value"
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "text": "data point",
      "values": [
        -4.69283003950355,
        -4.692830039503548,
        -4.6928300395035505
      ]
    }
  ],
  "title": {
    "text": "metrics over time"
  },
  "tooltip": {},
  "type": "line"
}
```

And I am planning to update those values every second or so. Here is my HTML side code:

```
<head>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
var myChart = {"refresh":{
    "type":"feed",
    "transport":"http",
    "url":"/metrics_feed",
    "interval":1000
    }
};
    window.onload=function(){
        zingchart.render({
            id:"myChartDiv",
            data:myChart,
            height:600,
            width:"100%"
        });
    };

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myChartDiv"></div>
</body>
```

And this all works when I copy the direct JSON in there instead of sending it over HTTP so there is something I am missing in the Zingcharts documentation I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on the ZingChart support team, and I'm happy to help you figure this out. You'll want to configure most of your chart settings and objects in your page, so in the myChart object. That means crosshair-x, legend, plot, etc... should all be static in the page and not passed via HTTP. In the JSON object, create empty series objects within the series array for each series that you will be passing to the chart. So, if you will only have one series plotted:

```
{
"type": "line",
"title": {
    "text": "metrics over time"
},
/* Additional objects (tooltip, legend, crosshair, etc...) omitted for brevity */
"series": [
    {
        "values": []
    }
    ]
}
```

And if you will be passing 2 series values:

```
{
"type": "line",
"title": {
    "text": "metrics over time"
},
/* Additional objects (tooltip, legend, crosshair, etc...) omitted for brevity */
"series": [
    {
        "values": []
    },
    {
        "values": []
    }
    ]
}
```

The "refresh" object should also be placed in the myData object, in the top level:

```
{
"type": "line",
"title": {
    "text": "metrics over time"
},
/* Additional objects (tooltip, legend, crosshair, etc...) omitted for brevity */
"refresh":{
    "type":"feed",
    "transport":"http",
    "url":"/metrics_feed",
    "interval":1000
},
"series": [
    {
        "values": []
    },
    {
        "values": []
    }
    ]
}
```

Depending on how many series objects you want in your chart, configure your script to pass values in the following format:

```
[ { "plot0" : 27, "plot1" : 34 } ]
```

Here's the feeds.php script that we use for [the chart under the HTTP section of our feeds article](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/feeds/#feeds__http):

```
<?php
$min = isset($_GET['min'])?intval($_GET['min']):0;
$max = isset($_GET['max'])?intval($_GET['max']):50;
$plots = isset($_GET['plots'])?intval($_GET['plots']):1;
?>
[
    {
        <?php
        for ($plot=0;$plot<$plots;$plot++) {
        ?>
        "plot<?php echo $plot; ?>" : <?php echo rand($min, $max); ?>,
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        "scale-x" : "<?php echo date('H:i:s'); ?>"
    }
]
```

This script also returns a timestamp that gets injected to an empty values array in our scale-x object. You can see a sample response [here](http://www.zingchart.com/resources/feed.php?min=0&max=50&plots=2).

I apologize if our docs did not make this clear, I'll be updating them with added clarification soon. Anyway, I hope that helps you! Let me know if you need some more help.